# Question about the Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, euclidean-algorithm

So about the Extended Euclidean algorithm, the algorithm that finds, `a`, `b`, and `d` in the equation `am+bn=d`, where `m` and `n` are two positive integers, `d` is their GCD, and `a` and `b` are two integers (not necessarily positive)

So the book I am following has the following instructions for implementing this algorithm:

```
E1. [Initialize.] Set a′ ← b ← 1, a ← b′ ← 0, c ← m, d ← n.

E2. [Divide.] Let q and r be the quotient and remainder, respectively,
      of c divided by d. (We have c = qd + r and 0 ≤ r < d.)

E3. [Remainder zero?] If r = 0, the algorithm terminates; 
      we have in this case am + bn = d as desired.

E4. [Recycle.] Set c ← d, d ← r, t ← a′, a′ ← a, a ← t − qa, t ← b′, b′ ← b, b ← t − qb, 
      and go back to E2.
```

My problem is that I don't particularly understand all the math around this algorithm, I understand the normal Euclidean algorithm well enough, so I understand half of the extended one as well. What I don't understand is the need for `a'` and `b'` as well `t` (I get that `t` is a temporary variable but I don't get the `a = t - qa` and `b = t - qb` part). That as well as the initialization of the variables `a`, `a'`, `b`, and `b'` as well as the swapping of the values between them on each iteration. Can anybody help me bridge these gaps in my understanding of this algorithm?

Comment: Does [this](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/extended-euclid-algorithm.html) help?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, thanks so much! If you put this as a solution, I can mark it as the accepted solution!

Comment: I would, except I would have to first study it more carefully so I could actually claim that knowledge :) it's all good.